# Youtube upload API Card end

Tags: python, youtube, upload, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to be able to activate end card from the youtube API to insert videos and put the subscription annotation to the end automatically.

Can the new end card (https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6388789) allow this and how? The card end will probably be the same every time but needs to be activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not yet supported in the YouTube Data API as of now. If you check the [revision history of the Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history), there is no update regarding that end screen for the videos. You can also always check the [YouTube Developers Blog](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/) for the update that they are doing for the YouTube API.