# How to replicate bulk end screen copy functionality from VidIQ and TubeBuddy?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am the owner of an [educational YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMOZpx9vI_3B_25K5zjGRng) with tens of thousands of short videos. I would like to get some more organic reach by implementing end screen cards on all videos that are already posted. Unfortunately, Youtube does not have a built-in feature to bulk-apply end screen cards.

This leads people to go to paid services such as TubeBuddy and VidIQ to gain that functionality. Unfortunately, due to the size of my channel, I am in no position to pay for these apps and so would like to use my programming knowledge to implement the functionality myself.

**Note:** VidIQ does have free bulk copy however I am limited to only updating the latest 3000 videos, of which only 2000 successfully updated since many of my videos don't have matching aspect ratios.

I've tried to look for an answer on google and on StackOverflow without success. From these three questions...

[How to add end screen with YouTube Data API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792678/how-to-add-end-screen-with-youtube-data-api)

[Is possible to add annotations or a 'end screen' to a video when i'm uploading it using Java youtube api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714071/is-possible-to-add-annotations-or-a-end-screen-to-a-video-when-im-uploading-i)

[Youtube upload API Card end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674363/youtube-upload-api-card-end)

... you would guess that it is impossible to do this but how is it done by TubeBuddy and vidIQ then? I highly suggest not reiterating the answers in the above three questions as **it is possible** since there are already multiple apps that implement it. The reason behind `youtube` tag is that it's most fitting however the answer can be anything from automation software to any specialized language imaginable I just simply cannot find any leads.